# JFace label provider overview

Tags: eclipse, jface

Is there any good overview of the JFace label provider framework? The [JFace snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets) doesn't really explain the relationship between the different generations (pre-3.2, 3.3, 3.4, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of good tutorials available.  You should know that you need to understand the complete Providerframework (Contentprovider, Labelprovider, Notifications, etc.).

Also, I the architecture between the various Eclipse-Versions barely changed.  Are you specifically looking for an Eclipse History?

You'll find plenty on Google.  Here are two starting points:

Eclipse Help-Center:

help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_render.htm

Vogella-Tutorial:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html

Good Luck

Comment: The JFace snippets refer to several generations of JFace/SWT API versions, e.g. "how to do X using pre-3.2 API". I'm looking for an overview of these changes, alternatively a good overview on The Right Way to do things using the most recent release.